# Why is this async handler error catching is different from normal try catch block?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

When I try to follow a tutorial. He is using a library called `express-async-handler` to handle async functions automatically

[Link to github npm](https://github.com/Abazhenov/express-async-handler)

The thing is that I try to convert that code into normal code without using library I see some different.

Here is the code with asyncHandler

```
router.get('/', asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    throw new Error('Error')
    res.json(products);
}))
```

As you can see there is an error thrown to the routes. When using asyncHandler the request status is change to 500 by middleware when error is thrown

```
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode
    res.status(statusCode)
    res.json({
        message: err.message,
    })
}
```

But when I try to use the normal `trycatch block`, The throw is not detected by the `error handler middleware`

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    res.json(products);
} catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
}
});
```

So what the difference between the codes , from my understanding the code i converted is correct. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not calling the `next` function with your error. Right now, you're catching the error, and simply setting the `json` on the response.

This means that nothing outside of this function knows about the error, since it's already been completely handled!

See if the following gets you more what you're looking for:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
    res.json(products);
} catch (err) {
    next(err)
}
});
```